# Why is the react component is rendering twice without changing the state?

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-lifecycle

First i added logs in the console for every life cycle hooks

```
class CircleA extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "Circle",
    };
    console.log("Circle-A constructor");
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    console.log("Circle-A getDeriveStateFromProps Method");
    return null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Circle-A componentDidMount Method");
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Circle-A render method");
    return <div>Circle-A</div>;
  }
}
```

After then, on the console every methods until `componentDidMount` are being called twice without updating the state.

These are the console messages

[image: i don't understand why is the constructor being called twice]

Comment: Do you have two `CircleA` components?

Comment: i only have one CircleA component and it was rendered only once

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of `React.StrictMode`. React can call render phase methods multiple times for detecting side-effects. You may want to check the index.js file or the main file where you are using `ReactDOM.render` to check whether you have a wrapper called `React.StrictMode`.

Here are the docs on same: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Hope this Helps!